# How to exclude 0 and blank cells when using excel MIN function

Tags: excel, formula, min

Got this formula:

```
{=IF(A4=MIN((C4=$C$4:$C$46711)*(B4=$B$4:$B$46711)*($A$4:$A$46711)),"First Event","All")}
```

I'm using the same one for MAX, and it works just fine. But when changing to MIN it fails, and I suppose it's because of value 0 and/or blank cells in my range. I've tried to add "ISNUMBER" after the "IF" but it doesn't do the trick...

How can this formua be modified to return lowest value, not counting 0 and/or blank cells in Column A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this function, you can use something like the below in place of your `MIN` function:

```
=MINIFS(A1:A10,A1:A10,"<>0")
```

If not, something like:

```
=MIN(IF(A1:A10<>0,A1:A10,""))
```

Depending on your version of Excel, you may need to "confirm" this **array-formula** it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar.

Substituting in your formula would look like:

```
=IF(A4=MIN(IF(((C4=$C$4:$C$46711)*(B4=$B$4:$B$46711)*$A$4:$A$46711)<>0,(C4=$C$4:$C$46711)*(B4=$B$4:$B$46711)*$A$4:$A$46711,"")),"First Event","All")
```

Comment: Got Excel 2016, and can't use MINIFS. Tried out the other one, but I'm not sure I'm getting the entire formula the way you're suggesting. Can I please ask you to write out the entire formula so that I can fully understand where the "=MIN(IF..."-part is supposed to be?

Comment: @kit99 See my Edit.

Comment: That last one did the trick [Ron Rosenfeld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2872922/ron-rosenfeld) Thanks a lot for helping out. :)

Answer (score 0):

I test your formula for a smaller range, there can be a smaller issue, which is causing trouble to you.
In your range $A$4:$A$46711 of the formula there can be a number or entry which is "text" formatted 
I have done the following three trials:
Trial 1. Try it with blanks
[image: Trying with blanks]
Trial 2. Try it with blanks and zeros too.

Result: In both the cases your formula, is working fine
[image: trial 2]

Trial 3: with Text in column A, It is generating an error
[image]
Hence I am concluding to check your A column range for any text formatting

Comment: Did you copy the formula to all rows in D4:D15? If I do the same thing, I get "All" in every cell in D4:D15. I was hoping to get "First event" in lowest A-value Jack (D4), Emily (D7), John (D6) and Lauren (D12), and "All" in the other cells...

Answer (score 0):

Remember you can also use Aggregate for these since Excel 2010:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,A1:A10/((A1:A10>0)*(B1:B10="a")),1)
```

[image]